# Solving nonlinear system of differential equation with Maxima

Tags: differential-equations, maxima

Is there any package to solve nonlinear system of differential equation with Maxima. like this:

```
eqn1: A(r)*E(r)/r-'diff(A(r),r)=5+1/r;
eqn2: r*'diff(E(r)/r)-A(r)^2/r=0;
```